# Flutter Multiple Image to Video Slideshow with Audio converter Using FFmpegKit

Tags: flutter, image, audio, ffmpeg, flutter-android

I want to render a video file using some images with animation.

I have tried some solution out there and i did not get any solution either I don't know how to write command of FFmpegKit. I also tried to first implement a single image with mp3 but it was also not working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want to execute this command    
 ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -t 3 -i img001.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 3 -i img002.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 3 -i img003.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 3 -i img004.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 3 -i img005.jpg \
-filter_complex \
"[0][1]xfade=transition=circlecrop:duration=0.5:offset=2.5[f0]; \
[f0][2]xfade=transition=smoothleft:duration=0.5:offset=5[f1]; \
[f1][3]xfade=transition=pixelize:duration=0.5:offset=7.5[f2]; \
[f2][4]xfade=transition=hblur:duration=0.5:offset=10[f3]" \
-map "[f3]" -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 output-swipe-custom.mp4

Comment: [source](https://www.bannerbear.com/blog/how-to-create-a-slideshow-from-images-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: i don't know how to execute this command with flutter

Comment: i just tried to execute using this command but it's not working :(  String command ="-y  -i ${f1.path} -i ${f2.path} -i ${f3.path} -filter_complex [0][1]xfade=transition=circlecrop:duration=0.5:offset=2.5[f0] [f0][2]xfade=transition=smoothleft:duration=0.5:offset=5[f1] [f1][3]xfade=transition=pixelize:duration=0.5:offset=7.5[f2] [f2][4]xfade=transition=hblur:duration=0.5:offset=10[f3] -map [f3] "
          "-r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 "
          "-shortest ${appDirectory!.path}/output.mp4";